# The requested version of macOS is not available. HOW TO FIX IT TUTORIAL. macOS Catalina public beta

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I'm unable to install catalina even after enrolling to the beta. it shows you mac is already uptodate.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After wasting a day trying to install beta 05 - macOS Catalina, here is the workaround I came across.

Here's how to fix it:

1. Open the terminal
2. Run code below

   ```
   sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --set-catalog https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.15beta-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz
   ```
3. now, delete the existing file if there is any.

   ```
   sudo rm /Users/Shared/.SeedEnrollment.plist
   ```
4. Create a file using nano.

   ```
   sudo nano /Users/Shared/.SeedEnrollment.plist
   ```
5. paste the following code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
   <key>SeedProgram</key>
   <string>PublicSeed</string>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

You can get away with command+c and command+v. 
Press control+z and then Y to save the file.

Now, things should be sorted out - check the update settings and it should display beta version.

Comment: Thanks!  This was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after I changed  "<string>PublicSeed</string>" to "<string>DeveloperSeed</string>".

Comment: I am getting this error for public release. Any solution.

Comment: confirming, works for me. In my case, issue gone after "step 2", `sudo /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --set-catalog https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.15beta-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz
`

Comment: Skipped Step 2, just had to do Step 4 + 5.  Just wanted the Catalina to Big Sur update.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the other suggestions with no luck, I was still stuck on `19A487l` with no way to upgrade.

These are the steps that finally worked for me:

1. Delete the SeedEnrollment plist entirely `sudo rm /Users/Shared/.SeedEnrollment.plist`
2. Uninstall *all* installed profiles, including my unrelated IKEv2 VPN profile
3. Apple provides 3 different DMGs to enroll in beta programs:

   - `macOSPublicBetaAccessUtility.dmg` (didn't work)
   - `macOSCatalinaDeveloperBeta.dmg` (didn't work)
   - **`macOSDeveloperBetaAccessUtility.dmg` this is the only one that worked for me**
     https://download.developer.apple.com/WWDC_2019/macOS_10.15_Developer_Beta_Access_Utility/macOSDeveloperBetaAccessUtility.dmg

   Download and install the package in the `macOSDeveloperBetaAccessUtility.dmg` DMG, but quit `System Preferences` the moment it's opened at the end.
4. Open the macOS `App Store.app` and Go to `Account > Sign Out`, quit and re-open the App Store, then sign back in with your developer Apple ID.
5. Go to https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina-beta/id1455661060?mt=12 which should open the macOS Catalina Beta in the `App Store`, click `Get` which should then open System Preferences and allow you to start downloading it.

During the download process it may fail at the end or halfway with `An error occurred while installing the selected updates.`, unfortunately I don't have any advice beyond that point other than to keep retrying the steps above until you get it working.  It took me a few tries and there seems to be no rhyme or reason to when it fails or works.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Step 5. did fail for me. But worked fine when I tried it again.

If it helps, the goal for this is to try to get the Catalina installer to run a full install again, not just do an update. Other Stack Overflow answers that were trying to fix the updater did not work for me.

1. Same, but no Terminal. Unenroll from Beta updates. System Preferences -> Software Update -> Details button (lower left corner) -> Restore Defaults. 

3. You can also get the beta profile installer from https://developer.apple.com/download/ 

4. I wasn’t signed in before/during/after

Answer (score 1):

Your mac shows it is already participating on the beta program (message below the gear) but something is wrong and it is not receiving the beta seed.

You can safely unenroll it, and enroll it again.

To unenroll click on "details" below the gear on that window, a dialog will appear asking if you would like to restore your default update settings. Choose 'Restore Defaults'.

After it, close System Preferences .

Download the Catalina public beta utility from: 
https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/redemption#macos

Install the utility and open System Preferences -> Software update.

It should work.